# Entity Framework: AutoMapper: ObjectStateManager exception thrown when setting EntityState.Modified on existing item

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am getting the following exception when trying to update my Player object.

```
An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
```

I am grabbing the entity, AutoMapping it to a DTO, editing it in a form, sending it back and converting back to a EF object before saving it.

```
public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public int PlayerId {get; set;}

    //visual only, not a foreign key
    public int PlayerCompetitionId {get;set;}

    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}

    [Column("ClubId")]
    public int? CurrentClubId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CurrentClubId")]
    public virtual Club CurrentClub { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerDTO
{
    public int PlayerId {get; set;}

    public virtual int PlayerCompetitionId {get;set;}

    public virtual string FirstName {get; set;}
    public virtual string LastName {get; set;}

    public virtual Club CurrentClub { get; set; }
}

public class Club
{
     public int ClubId {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Here are my AutoMapper mappings:-

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Player, PlayerDTO>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PlayerDTO, Player>()
            .ForMember(x => x.CurrentClubId, opt => opt.MapFrom(dto => (dto.CurrentClub.ClubId == 0) ? null : dto.CurrentClub.ClubId as int?))
            .ForMember(x => x.CurrentClub, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

When I save the DTO object back, I can see that the mapping looks fine.
But when I go to set the EntityState to modified I get the above exception.

Here is my final mapping code and save.

```
public void SetModified(DTOPlayer updatedPlayer)
{
    Player player = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Player>(updatedPlayer);

    this.Entry(player).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Is the problem with my nullable int property? 
Because I have another DTO model which saves correctly when I do the exact same thing.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the this.Entry(player).State = EntityState.Modified; method?

Comment: That is public DbEntityEntry Entry(object entity); from EntityFramework. It's in DbContext.
Should probably be more explicit with 'base' instead of 'this'.

Answer (score 1):

In your code your creating a new player object. That method is trying to add it as well as set to modified, but it is already there. I think you need to get the player from the context, then map the DTO's values into it. In which case you shouldn't even need to set to modified - it should happen automagically.

```
public void SetModified(DTOPlayer updatedPlayer)
{
    Player player = // however you get that particular player from the db context

    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<DTOPlayer, Player>(updatedPlayer, player);
}
```

Comment: So this worked, however now I'm confused about how my other models work fine with the other method. (Just Automapping, SetModified, and Save). I didn't have to grab the original from the context. I assumed because the Primary Keys were the same, it would be fine.  Any idea why that is?

Comment: Yeah, that had me scratching my head as well. Perhaps your sending entities to the other methods that do not exist yet, or maybe your PK's are messed up or non existent. Thanks for the edit btw did this in notepad :)

Comment: No problem. Thanks for helping me out. I'm going to do a bit more research and get to the bottom of this before I choose this as the selected answer.